Is there a way to find first non zero value for a lookup value in excel
can anyone please help me find first non zero value for a lookup in excel. Example, in the below table, when I lookup for 1, with respect to column2, I should get value 'b', not blank or #NA.

I found answers here to get the column headers, but I want the actual value.

If you have Excel 365 you can use this formula:
=TAKE(FILTER(B2:B5,(A2:A5=1)*(B2:B5<>"")),1)
It filters column2 for non-empty values where value in column 1 equals 1.
And then takes the first result.

Thank you Ike. What I am working on is two sheets, one having column 1 data of input, and another sheet having columns 1 and 2 and it is a large dataset. Formula worked for single sheet but didn't work even when I replaced the range A2:A5 with the the lookup value column in sheet 2. Am I making any mistake...?

Just select those values from Sheet2 when defining the range within the formula

You can use index/match with older versions of Excel:
=INDEX(B2:B5,MATCH(1,(A2:A5=1)*(B2:B5<>""),0))

Match finds the position of the first '1' in column A that does not have an empty cell in the same row in column B then index shows the contents of the cell in column B.
May need to confirm the formula with CtrlShiftEnter

Thank you Tom, I am working on two separate excel sheets, need to extract data with respect to lookup value from a different sheet altogether
